# Passenger v5.2.0 inside Alpine v3.7 Docker container - SIGSEGV(11)

Tags: docker, segmentation-fault, passenger, alpine-linux

I have been working on creating a minimal Rails GraphQL docker container based on Alpine 3.7 running Passenger 5.2.0. Unfortunately, Passenger keeps crashing and I am unsure what the cause is.

**This is the head of the Passenger log file**

```
[ N 2018-02-06 16:40:25.3740 14/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1252 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2018-02-06 16:40:25.4056 17/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1242 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2018-02-06 16:40:25.4059 17/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:252 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2018-02-06 16:40:25.4244 17/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:977 ]: Passenger core online, PID 17
App 55 stdout: 
[ pid=17, timestamp=1517935227 ] Process aborted! signo=SIGSEGV(11), reason=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=0x0, randomSeed=1517935225
```

**And this is the end of the Passenger log file**

```
[ W 2018-02-06 16:27:28.8642 14/T4 age/Wat/AgentWatcher.cpp:97 ]: Passenger core (pid=17) crashed with signal SIGSEGV, restarting it...
2018/02/06 16:27:28 [error] 38#0: *4 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/app/current/tmp/passenger.pnTbJGQ/agents.s/core:", host: "0.0.0.0"
[ N 2018-02-06 16:27:28.8808 86/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1242 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2018-02-06 16:27:28.8812 86/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:252 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2018-02-06 16:27:28.9032 86/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:977 ]: Passenger core online, PID 86
```

**Lastly, here are the relevant files (including the Passenger log with backtrace, Dockerfile, etc)**

https://gist.github.com/nater540/c22414d21bf22a990a474c93936b7c06

If anyone has any suggestions or insight that would be absolutely fantastic!

Comment: I would post an issue over on passenger's GitHub repository (maybe just link to SO).  I think they will be better able to diagnose your issue.

Comment: @DerekBrown Yeah, I did that shortly after posting this question => https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2030

Comment: Solid!  That is definitely your best bet.